# QUERY_STRING in .htaccess While redirecting

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

How can I allow visitors to use this link (www.example.com/news?id=34) in order to see (www.example.com/index.php?page=news&id=34)

Right now I am hiding the extensions of my PHP files in order to make the links look nice. When visitors go to (www.example.com/news) they can see the page (www.example.com/index.php?page=news). However, when they go to (www.example.com/news?id=12) they get a 404 error.

At this point, PHP does not recognize the id parameter. Here is what I currently have in my .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# catch request with no querystring like /Home
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]

# make other requests with a non-empty query string go to /index.php?id=XXXXX
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second test pattern (`^$`) only matches the case where the user doesn't put any path information in, but does include a query string (e.g. *www.example.com/?id=12*). Also note that the backreference `$1` has no value in that rule either.

The simplest solution is to just combine the two rules, since you can use the `QSA` flag to do the work of appending the `id=#` part for you:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I really really really really really appreciate your help. You totally saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

The condition of your first rule fails as the query is not empty. Try it without that condition but with the following condition instead:

```
RewriteCond $1 !=index.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```